# Is this join correct?

Tags: mysql, join

I am very new to MySQL joins and I have put this together, it is working but I don't know if there is a better way to do this??

```
$q = $dbc -> prepare("SELECT l.layout, a.email 
                      FROM layout AS l 
                      JOIN accounts AS a ON (l.id = a.id) 
                      WHERE email = ?");
$q -> execute(array($_POST['email']));
```

Basically there are 2 tables one called layout and one called accounts, I want to select the layout from layout where the email that matches the id in accounts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be a better way. Yours is fine.  The only suggestion is not to use the `AS` keyword for table aliases.  The `AS` in that position is valid in MySQL, but just isn't commonly used.  It may not be valid in every RDBMS so it may be best to not to get in the habit of using.

```
SELECT l.layout, a.email 
FROM layout l JOIN accounts a ON (l.id = a.id) 
--          ^               ^
-- alias follows table name directly
WHERE email = ?
```

Comment: Ok why is that? I used it only as it is easier to read the code.

Comment: @pv1 see my addition. It's valid MySQL but not in every RDBMS.

Comment: Funny: I would advise putting the AS in because in the DBMS I mostly work with (Informix), it protects you from future keyword additions.  Since the SQL standard says AS is permitted, I would expect most DBMS to allow it.  (Informix works happily without the AS provided the alias used is not a keyword; if it becomes a keyword in a future release, then the query that used to work is apt to break - but AS keeps it working.)

Comment: I use `AS` too wherever possible or when I don't forget. I think Oracle doesn't accept it (yet) for table aliases.

Comment: @ypercube Right - Oracle is what I was thinking of. I thought SQL Server didn't like it either, but tested when I got in to work and SQL Server does accept `AS` in that position.